# How to copy paste data after using group_by in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given the following dummy data:

```
data <- data.frame(pnr = c('a43','a4945', 'a43', 'a231', 'a231', 'a6901'),
                date = c(as.Date('2011-12-19'), as.Date('2012-09-11'),  as.Date('2013-10-01'),
                as.Date('2012-05-09'), as.Date('2009-09-10'), as.Date('2015-06-12')),
                complication = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

In the duplicates, I want to copy paste the data from `complication` from the first surgery to a new column `prevcomp` in the row of second surgery in patients that occur twice (they occur either once or twice, not more). So this is what I want in the end:

```
    pnr       date complication  prevcomp
1   a43 2011-12-19            1        NA   # first operation
2 a4945 2012-09-11            0        NA   # no duplicate
3   a43 2013-10-01            0         1   # second op: copy paste complication from first op
4  a231 2012-05-09            0         0   # second op: copy paste complication from first op
5  a231 2009-09-10            0        NA   # first
6 a6901 2015-06-12            0        NA   # no duplicate
```

I want to use the `dplyr` package and have done very short this far:

```
data %>%
    group_by(pnr) %>%
```

Now I don't know how to copy the `complication` from the one with `min(date)`, and insert it to `prevcomp` with `max(date)`. I do understand I need to use `mutate` to insert the value somehow:

```
    mutate(prevcomp = ...)
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `dplyr::lag` for this (within a group), where it brings in the previous row's data (within the group); when looking at the first row in a group (where there is no "previous"), it uses the `default=` value, which is normally `NA`.

```r
data %>%
  group_by(pnr) %>%
  mutate(prevcomp = lag(complication)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   pnr   date       complication prevcomp
#   <chr> <date>            <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 a43   2011-12-19            1       NA
# 2 a4945 2012-09-11            0       NA
# 3 a43   2013-10-01            0        1
# 4 a231  2012-05-09            0       NA
# 5 a231  2009-09-10            0        0
# 6 a6901 2015-06-12            0       NA
```

**Edit**: since you likely want this done in date-order, `lag` is not honoring the date ordering, that needs to be done first. This changes the output from your expected output, but I think perhaps that this is what you are asking for:

```r
data %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(pnr) %>%
  mutate(prevcomp = lag(complication)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   pnr   date       complication prevcomp
#   <chr> <date>            <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 a231  2009-09-10            0       NA
# 2 a43   2011-12-19            1       NA
# 3 a231  2012-05-09            0        0
# 4 a4945 2012-09-11            0       NA
# 5 a43   2013-10-01            0        1
# 6 a6901 2015-06-12            0       NA
```

Bottom line, `dplyr::lag` operates in row-order, whatever it is at the time.

You can control the "distance" `k` (how many rows back to go), that defaults to `k=1`; with `lag(complication, k=2)`, one would bring forward the value from 2 rows ago.

There is also `dplyr::lead`, for looking *forward* `k` rows.

(Note that I mentioned the use of `dplyr::lag`; there is also a `stats::lag` function that does not do what you want here.)

Comment: would lag arrange the data in date order? The dates of the rows in the dataset do not occur in order.

Comment: No, you will need to `arrange(date)` first.

Comment: Actually, I had assumed that the order was already relevant to you. In this case, `a231`'s rows are not in order, but you're showing a `0` in the *first* occurrence of that `pnr`, where re-reading your question, I would expect it to be the second row. Is that intentional?

Comment: Ah my fault sorry

Comment: See my edit, I provide both with and without, I think it addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

`lag` is already in use by r2evans. I tried to get the logic from the OP. Please tell me if this is what you are looking for.

```
data %>%
  group_by(pnr) %>% 
  mutate(group_count = n())%>% 
  mutate(group = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  arrange(group, date) %>% 
  mutate(prevcomp = ifelse(group_count > 1, lag(complication), NA)) %>% 
  select(-group_count, -group)
```

Output:

```
  pnr   date       complication prevcomp
  <chr> <date>            <dbl>    <dbl>
1 a231  2009-09-10            0       NA
2 a231  2012-05-09            0        0
3 a43   2011-12-19            1       NA
4 a43   2013-10-01            0        1
5 a4945 2012-09-11            0       NA
6 a6901 2015-06-12            0       NA
```